# Change label of gganimate frame title

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, gganimate

Skimming through the options of `gganimate` that can be set when `gg_animate()` is called to render the animated sequence, it seems that there is no option to change the frame title so to make it clearer to the observer of what is the parameter that the frame is based on.

In other words, suppose that `frame = year` in a layer: how do I make the frame's title be `year: ####` where #### is the year of the current frame? Am I missing something or is it a limitation of the `gganimate` library?

How would you achieve the same result by a workaround?
Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### Update for new `gganimate` API

`gganimate` has been redesigned with a [new API](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate). The frame title can now be animated with the code below. `state_length` and `transition_length` set the relative amount of time spent in a given "state" (meaning a given value of `cyl` here) and transitioning between states. `closest_state` means that while transitioning between states (which are the integer values of `cyl` in this case) the `cyl` value closest to the current transition value should be shown (e.g., since `cyl` can be 4, 6, or 8, values between, say, 4 and 5 are displayed as 4 and values between 5 and 6 are displayed as 6):

```
p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  transition_states(cyl, transition_length=1, state_length=30) +
  labs(title = 'Cylinders: {closest_state}')

animate(p, nframes=40)
```

`gganimate` can be installed from `github` by running   `devtools::install_github('thomasp85/gganimate')`

The [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gganimate/vignettes/gganimate.html) has more details on how to use the new API.

#### Original Answer

The frame's subset value is appended to any pre-existing title. You can therefore add a title with explanatory text. For example:

```
library(gganimate)

p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, frame=cyl)) + geom_point() + 
    ggtitle("Cylinders: ")

gg_animate(p)
```

As you can see in the GIF below, the prefix "Cylinders: " is now added to the title before the value of `cyl`:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks! Can you point me to some other resources about gganimate?

Comment: If using transition_time instead of transition_states you can swap '{closest_state}' for '{frame_time}'

Comment: @eipi10 you might want to remove the first tutorial link in your comment here.

Comment: Thanks @Jojo! Hadn't had that happen to a link before!