# How to refer to other variables in labels (labs) using gganimate

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, plot, gganimate

Related to this question, [Display different time elements at different speeds in gganimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411936/display-different-time-elements-at-different-speeds-in-gganimate), suppose I have this MWE that creates a plot with `ggplot2` and `gganimate`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
a <- ggplot(airquality, aes(Day, Temp, 
                            group = interaction(Month, Day))) +
  geom_point(color = 'red', size = 1) +
  transition_time(Month) +
  shadow_mark(colour = 'black', size = 0.75) +
  enter_fade() +
  labs(title = paste('Month: {frame_time}')) +
animate(a, nframes = 100)
```

Note that it labels it with the month, which comes from the `{frame_title}` element, which corresponds to the value in `transition_time`, in this case the month. Is there a way to refer to a different variable in the label? For example, say that there are two new columns, `number` and `color`. The `number` column is just the number of the month, so the first month that appears will be a 1, the second will be a two, and so on. The `color` will just be different colors. The key is that they each map to `Month`. How can I refer to these other variables within `labs`?

Comment: Duplicate of [Display different time elements at different speeds in gganimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411936/display-different-time-elements-at-different-speeds-in-gganimate)

Comment: I understand that why you asked this question. To find a workaround for the other problem. But this is what's called [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I answered your question on the other thread which also addresses this one. Cheers.