# Do if then statement based on values inside data frame or vector

Tags: r, if-statement, logic

As an example, suppose I have this data:

```
key <- data.frame(num=c(1,2,3,4,5), month=c("January", "Feb", "March", "Apr", "May"))
data <- c(4,2,5,3)
```

I want to create a new vector, `data2` using the mapping of `num` to `month` contained in `key`. I can do this manually using `case_when` by  doing lots of if statements at once:

```
library(dplyr)
data2<-case_when(
    data==1 ~ "January",
    data==2 ~ "Feb",
    data==3 ~ "March",
    data==4 ~ "Apr",
    data==5 ~ "May"
)
```

However, say that I want to automate this process (maybe I actually have thousands of if statements) and utilize the mapping contained in `key`. Is this, or something like it, possible?

Here is a failed attempt at code:

```
data2 <- case_when(data=key$num ~ key$month)
```

What I am going for is a vector called `data2` with these elements: `c("Apr","Feb","May","March")`. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm certain there is a way to do it with `case_when`, but this can be done via subsetting - `key$month[match(data, key$num)]` for instance.

Comment: `data2 <- data.frame(num = data) %>% left_join(key) %>% pull(month)`. (And you probably want to load `key` with `stringsAsFactors = F`)

Comment: Ideally, it would use `case_when` so that I can do this with a function. The real reason I am asking has to do with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411936/display-different-time-elements-at-different-speeds-in-gganimate/56418594?noredirect=1#comment99464431_56418594 See my comment to the answer. Hopefully one of these answers can apply there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` and base R indexing (also, set stringsAsFactors=FALSE when you initialize the data.frame, as I did below):

```
key <- data.frame(num=c(1,2,3,4,5), month=c("January", "Feb", "March", "Apr", "May"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data2 <- key$month[match(data, key$num)]
data2
#[1] "Apr"   "Feb"   "May"   "March"
```